# Subtract two pixels-only- layers using rectangle extent

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, change-detection, landsat-7

I have code in GEE that:

- calculates the NDVI in a given polygon, from 2000 (based on Landsat 7) and 2019 (Landsat 8)
- creates for each one a layer with pixels that their NDVI value is higher than 0.3
- then subtract them from each other in order to detect change.

The problem is that when I run my code the result is that there is no difference.
I think maybe GEE doesn't do the subtraction if the pixels are not on the same location so I always get no change.

Maybe it will be easier to understand from my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/98102459e86cc67232896d226f19565b

Basically I have created two layers in a long process and in this specific line:

```js
for (var i in listOfNumbers1){
  var imageNDVI1 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[i]));
  var hot2019 = imageNDVI1.gt(0.3)
  .selfMask()
  .rename('hotspot03');
Map.addLayer(hot2019,{palette: '0000ff'},'2019');}
```

and then I subtract the two layers (hot2000 and hot 2010) like this:

```js
var difference = hot2019.subtract(hot2000);

Map.addLayer(difference,{min:-1, max:1 ,palette: ['ff3300', 'a3a375','009933']},'difference');
```

My end goal is to get new layer that will be calssified into 3 values: -1, 0 and 1.

- I thought maybe the reason it happened is because it doesn't have rectangle extent
- Any polygon would work. I have checked Delhi and New Mexico

Comment: Please, try to recreate this problem with a minimal script. Right now, it's a lot of code, making it hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow all your steps, but I did notice one error when you add a map layer:

```
Map.addLayer(hot2019,{palette: '0000ff'},'2019');
```

When you have a palette with one single color, that's the color you will get on your map, no matter what value you have. In your case, you have three discrete values: -1, 1, 1, so you'd want to provide three colors in your palette.

This could maybe give you some ideas:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f6e883e6bd03a8f413eab5aa19a269d